# Problem with cycled import in datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

Hi I have 2 functions these functions have a different types of import of datetime. I know where is problem but I do not know how to solute it

my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
def upload_video(title,description,tags,upload_year,uplaod_month,upload_day):
    upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(upload_year,uplaod_month,upload_day, 8, 00, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'
    print(f"this is a upload time {upload_date_time}")

    request_body = {
        'snippet': {
            'categoryI': 19,
            'title': title,
            'description': description,
            'tags': tags
        },
        'status': {
            'privacyStatus': 'private',
            'publishAt': upload_date_time,
            'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
        },
        'notifySubscribers': False
    }

    mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('output.MP4')

    response_upload = service.videos().insert(
        part='snippet,status',
        body=request_body,
        media_body=mediaFile
    ).execute()

def date_calculator():
    days_in_months = {1:31, 2:28, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}

    year = datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.now().month

    # Read the last used date from the text file
    with open("last_used_date.txt", "r") as f:
        last_used_date = f.read().strip()

    # If the file is empty or the date is invalid, set the last used date to the current date
    if not last_used_date or not all(c.isdigit() for c in last_used_date.split(".")):
        last_used_day = datetime.now().day
        last_used_month = month
    else:
        last_used_day, last_used_month = map(int, last_used_date.split(".")[:2])

    # Generate new dates until the next one is greater than the current date
    number = 0
    number_test = 1
    while True:
        date = "{}.{}.{}".format(last_used_day, last_used_month, year)
        number += 1

        if last_used_day == days_in_months[month]:
            last_used_month += 1
            last_used_day = 1 
        else:
            last_used_day += 1

        if number == 2:
            last_used_day += 1
            number = 0

        number_test += 1

        if (last_used_month > month or
            (last_used_month == month and last_used_day > datetime.now().day)):
            with open("last_used_date.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write("{}.{}.{}".format(last_used_day, last_used_month, year))
            break
    return last_used_day,last_used_month,year
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare
> livestyle\main.py", line 233, in 
> day,month,year = date_calculator()   File "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare
> livestyle\main.py", line 162, in date_calculator
> year = datetime.now().year AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

if I will change imports like this:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

error will look like that:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare
> livestyle\main.py", line 235, in 
> upload_video(title,"#Shorts", ["motivation", "business", "luxury", "entrepreneurship", "success", "lifestyle", "inspiration", "wealth",
> "financial freedom", "investing", "mindset", "personal development",
> "self-improvement", "goals", "hustle", "ambition", "rich life",
> "luxury lifestyle", "luxury brand", "luxury travel", "luxury
> cars"],year,month,day)   File
> "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare
> livestyle\main.py", line 74, in upload_video
> upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(upload_year,uplaod_month,upload_day, 8, 00,
> 0).isoformat() + '.000Z' AttributeError: type object
> 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: You can't have the same name mean two different things simultaneously. Pick **one** import and then fix the other function to use it in the same way.

Comment: FWIW this is a holdover from a long time ago, and imo the class names should've been capitalized to begin with (i.e. `from datetime import Date, Time, DateTime`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `datetime` module and the `datetime` class inside it are spelled exactly the same way. You need to pick one of those things to import and then use it consistently. i.e. either:

```
import datetime          # I want the whole datetime module
datetime.datetime.now()  # Must use the fully qualified class name
datetime.date.today()    # But I can also use other classes from the module
```

Or:

```
from datetime import datetime  # I only want the datetime class
datetime.now()                 # Use the class directly
```

The name `datetime` can only mean one thing at a time, so if you do both imports, all that's happening is that the second meaning overwrites the first one.